# Trigger not updating

Tags: php, mysql

I have a trigger that looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER findavg after INSERT 
ON rating 
FOR EACH row 
  UPDATE `profile` 
  SET    userscore = (SELECT Avg(rscore) 
                      FROM   rating 
                      WHERE  `profile`.`pid` = rating.raterid) 
  WHERE  pid = new.pid;
```

where

```
PROFILE table - pID, name, userScore

RATING table - raterID, rScore, rDescription
```

It works at the first time I implemented this trigger, however yesterday I dropped all the data in both **Profile and Rating** table. Thus, I inserted a "freshly new" data for profile and rating.

Now everytime I insert a "RATING", the trigger **won't update** the userScore.

So right now, I have some PROFILE that have "**0**" in userScore, even though in RATING table the value is "6" for the rScore.

I'm confused because I'm pretty sure based on syntax, it's correct already.

Help me please. Thank you.

Comment: If you run this in your database, it works? `UPDATE PROFILE SET userScore = (SELECT AVG(rScore) from RATING where PROFILE.pID=RATING.raterID) WHERE pID = someId`

Comment: are you sure the trigger didnt drop after you drop the tables?

Comment: How exactly did you drop the data in the rating table? Which command did you use?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza we seem to be thinking along the same lines :)

Comment: @Shadow Well if the trigger work before and now doesnt, the most like it is isnt linked to the table now.

Comment: BTW: You should change this trigger to `BEFORE INSERT` and you will save one update to the DB.

Comment: new.pid ??? is `new` a table in your database or you just wrote it this way??

Comment: additionally can you post the table schema with keys?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte no, even if I added manually, it doesn't work

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza no, I didn't drop the trigger. But I just did and paste the same code again in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Shadow I dropped it manually, using checkmark each row and drop.

Comment: @PeterDarmis I just wrote it that way because that's part of the trigger syntax right?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza BEFORE would probably result in an avg calculation being always one step behind.

Comment: @MasAdam: if you drop a table, then mysql drops all triggers associated with it. So, if you deleted the data by dropping and recreating the table, then you deleted the trigger as well.

Comment: Are you sure `profile.pid = rating.raterid` is the appropriate comparison? If so, maybe try uncorrelating the subquery by using new.pid there as well.

Comment: `new.pid`? `pid` doesn't exist in the table `rating`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `findavg` AFTER INSERT ON `rating`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE `profile`
  SET `userscore` = (SELECT AVG(`rscore`)
                     FROM `rating`
                     WHERE `raterid` = `pid`)
-- WHERE `pid` = NEW.`pid`;
  WHERE `pid` = NEW.`raterid`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3269b/3)

Comment: YES! Turns out my mistake is in the last line `WHERE pid = NEW.pid`. I didn't realized that I used pid = new.pid. Thanks!